# Creating a special list of unique elements

Tags: python, list, unique

I have a list defined like so

```
Q_opt_sc = [156910.6415400822, 4751.550104625496, 9088.02683003525, 14715.639401878929, 21303.41462556098, 28596.689807940442]
```

There are 6 elements. I need to create a list of unique duplicates on python. Each duplicate has 6 elements (from list above) and each element either takes element of list above or 0.

In other words, I need a list of all duplicates of type

```
duplicate_i = [[0 or Q_opt_sc[0]], [0 or Q_opt_sc[1]], 
               [0 or Q_opt_sc[2]], [0 or Q_opt_sc[3]],
               [0 or Q_opt_sc[4]], [0 or Q_opt_sc[5]], 
               [0 or Q_opt_sc[6]]]

list_of_all_duplicates = [duplicate_1, duplicate_2, ..., duplicate_n]
```

Comment: I think "duplicate" may not be the right word here. Do you mean all unique, 6-element lists one can construct by choosing either 0 or `Q_opt_sc[i]` for `0 <= i < 6`?

Comment: yes, I think your interpretation is correct

Answer (score 0):

Could use `itertools.product()` to create the individual elements that describe whether or not an index will use the list or a zero.
[0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,1]....

Then create a new list based on the setting of the product elements.

```
from itertools import product

Q_opt_sc = [156910.6415400822, 4751.550104625496, 9088.02683003525, 14715.639401878929, 21303.41462556098, 28596.689807940442]

list_of_all_duplicates = [[Q_opt_sc[i] if select else 0 for i,select in enumerate(e)] for e in product([0,1], repeat=6)]
print(list_of_all_duplicates[50])   # just to see one of them.
```

Output

```
[156910.6415400822, 4751.550104625496, 0, 0, 21303.41462556098, 0]
```

Comment: Thany you very very much! This is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: If the answer works for you, please make sure you accept it by clicking the green checkmark.